# How to detect First time login in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I want **detect when a user log in for first time**. I know i can do this using `Devise`, but how do I implement it without `Devise`?

I know i can set some flag in session, but how can I use it to detect the first time log in? I have the `current_user`  and the `user` table where I can add one more column such as `login_count` and I can  increment it every time when the user login.

Is it a good idea or is there another way to get the first time login?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case you don't want to include gem, then the better idea is to save in a column (ex: login_count)against the record.

Else Devise a best idea to keep `sign_in_count`

Comment: thanks  @Debadatt,both the anwers are indentical and i think this is the only best way to detecting first time or nth times login by a new column and then using it.

Answer (score 0):

Devise itself uses a `sign_in_count` column on it's users table, and that's what it uses to detect a first login, so yes, it's a good idea.